# Appcelerator Building the Millennial Media Module for IOS

Tags: iphone, module, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, millennial-media

I got the files for the Millennial Media module for Appcelerator from the following link:
https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.millennialmedia

I have built the .zip file and install the module in my project. When calling for example the ad banner with the following code:

```
win.add(MillennialMedia.createView({
  apid: '234859',
  bottom: 0,
  width: 320,
  height: 50,
  adType: MillennialMedia.TYPE_BANNER
}));
```

I get an error saying:

Error: invalid method (createView) passed to TiMillennialmediaModule

Ideas?

Using Titanium SDK 6.0.1.GA
Testing on IOS

Comment: This module have the createView method? https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.millennialmedia/blob/master/ios/example/app.js

Comment: Yes, if you look in the bottom.js file

Comment: https://github.com/appcelerator-archive/ti.millennialmedia/tree/master/ios/example

Comment: Weird, when I've built my first and only module, I could't figure out where to change the name of the createView function, so, by default, it stayed as createExample

Comment: So what's my solution from here?

Answer (score 0):

What's the version of the module?

My suggestion is to remove the old version and install manually the latest one: v3.1.1.

Other thing, I've noticed that in the manifest file for iOS, the apiversion version is 2, I don't know if it's only needed to change to 3 on android or id this applies also to iOS.

Any way, have you tried to compile the module with the minSdk set to 6.0.0?
In the manifest file is: minsdk: 3.4.1.GA

Rebuild the module it's only necessary if you are using android so that's not your case but here goes the: [Tim Poulson’s Blog Post](http://skypanther.com/2016/10/rebuilding-modules-for-titanium-6/).

Comment: I tried what you said, (clean project, remove old module, updated to apiversion 3, set min SDK to 6.0.0GA, installed 3.1.1), and this is the error message I get: http://www.bistech.ca/error.png.